# Is there a way to keep chocolate chips from melting in chocolate-chip waffles?

Tags: chocolate, waffle

My memory might be playing tricks on me, but I swear I've had chocolate chip waffles (or maybe pancakes) where the chocolate chips were still somewhat hard - in other words, not completely melted.   Every time I try, even if waiting for the batter to start cooking before adding the chips, they always seem to melt completely.  Waiting for the chips to harden would also mean the waffles get cold.  Any solution?

Comment: You could use cocoa nibs, instead of chocolate chips.  Same flavor, or nearly so (though less sweet, of course), but they won't melt and can give a bit of texture if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't fathom why you would want unmelted chocolate chips in your waffle or pancakes, some things you can try is:

- Using darker chocolate. Dark chocolate will has a slightly higher melting point than milk chocolate or semi-sweet chocolate. And since pancakes and waffles are usually eaten with syrup and other sweet toppings, it shouldn't be a problem that the chocolate is less sweet.
- Use cold chocolate chips. Leave the chocolate chips in the refrigerator prior to making the pancake/waffles.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tips Jay gave you, or you could try to put in modelling chocolate 'chips' instead of chocolate chips. Modelling chocolate is a paste, so those chips won't be hard, but I've heard it doesn't melt, so it wouldn't be as soft as melted real chocolate chips. Since it's just (light corn) syrup and chocolate, I guess the flavour would be fine in waffles.

Answer (score 3):

Freezing the chips before adding them may slow the melting process while they are inside the waffle batter that has already been poured into the iron.  Thermal trip from frozen to melted is longer than room temp to melted.  Although 3-5 minutes inside a waffle iron will most likely melt regular chocolate chips from any temperature.

Bigger chips might partially solve the problem, they'll take longer to melt since they have more mass for the heat to work through.  In the US, Ghirardelli chocolate chips are a little bigger than, say, Nestlé chocolate chips.  Chocolate chunks would also function as "bigger chips."

The chocolate chips you see inside a pancake are added after the pancake has cooked fully on one side and just before flipping to finish off by browning the other side so the chocolate chips have spend much less time in contact with heat.